# Python Bottle Framework - Shared Function Not Run in Parallel With Endpoints

Tags: python, bottle

I have a fairly standard Python bottle api.  Several of the api's endpoint share utility functions.  It looks like the utility function is not called in parallel???

In the code sample below, the api has two endpoints, foo and bar.  My understanding is that if foo and bar were called simultaneously, two separate threads are created to process them.  So the util_func should be executed in the scope of those threads.

I am seeing two separate threads created.  But the util_func seems to be blocked by last calling thread.  For example, if called bar then foo.  util_func in bar gets blocked until util_func in foo completes.  Then util_func in bar completes.

Is this the expected behavior???  The only difference in my code is that the util_func is a separate module.

```
def util_func():
    # do stuff

@app.route(/foo)
def foo():
    util_func()
    # do other stuff

@app.route(/bar)
def bar():
   util_func()
   # do other stuff

bottle.run(app=app,host='localhost', port=8888,server='cherrypy')
```

Comment: Yes, it is expected behavior, assuming that `util_func` does not make any I/O calls.  Only one Python thread runs at a time.  See https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have hit a [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) issue.

If you we'll write

```
def util_func(): 
    time.sleep(10) #10 long seconds...
```

You should see them running in parallel

If you will provide more details on util_func I would provide more help